# How to find the minimal number of bits to encode a set of known strings?

Tags: algorithm, compression

How to find the minimal number of bits to encode a set of known strings?

Comment: "the least number of bits possible" is provably not knowable. Read up on Kolmogorov Complexity.

Comment: @MarkAdler does this mean that there is no way to find this least number of bits or that there is no efficient algorithms other than brute force?

Comment: And can the person who downvotes this pose explain please?

Comment: As I said, read up on it.

Comment: @user136266: one reason for the downvote (which wasn't mine) could be the rhetorical nature of the question. How can we know what issues you had doing a simple internet search? Perhaps you misspelled a search term . Perhaps you used an inferior search engine. Perhaps you didn't recognise the search result when you saw it. No-one can say except you because you provide no details on how you attempted to search. Even if you had, the question would​ be out of scope, since SO is about programming, not effective use of internet search tools.

Comment: so funny that people think they know the answer and then downvote the post, thinking that I didn't do enough research. My question is not about whether there are more efficient ways of doing things like that suggested by @rici, is about getting me the minimal number of bits possible. I will reopen a new post so that it is not contaminated by naive people's downvotes

Comment: @user136266: My answer is precisely about the minimal bit length for transmitting elements from a set. You can only answer that question in the context of what the possible messages are, which is why either the ordinal index or the hoffman-encoded ordinal index are optimal (depending on how much information you have). See [Information Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) and particularly the seminal work of Claude Shannon.

Comment: @rici Example: I have 101 and 110. The minimum bits to encode this string is 2, since you have to see 2 bits before u can decide which is which. How does your huffman code solve this problem? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: If those are the only two possible sequences, one of them corresponds to code 0 and the other to code 1. Another way to think about that is that it is unnecessary to send the initial 1 because you know in advance that it must be sent, nor do you need to send the last bit since it is always the reverse of the second one. That might help your intuitions but the simple algorithm is the one I suggest: number the possibilities and send the ordinal.

Answer (score 2):

If the set of strings is known to both sender and receiver, then you need zero bits to transmit it. (In effect, the message is "Use the known set." I know that sounds silly, but it is often part of a comms protocol.)

If you need to send a single string from the set, you can send its ordinal index, using log<sub>2</sub> *N* bits, where *N* is the size of the set.

if you are repeatedly sending messages containing a single string from the set but the frequency distribution of the messages is non-uniform, you can Hoffman-code the ordinal. That will optimize the total size of all messages over time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly if you require this one but still have a look at it , it might help you . Let me know if it does:
[Compression algorithm](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223610/A-Simple-String-Compression-Algorithm)